# How would I take pycharm data into an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: pycharm

How would I go about getting data I have webscraped from a website using pycharm and then putting it into an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: What do you mean by "webscraped using pycharm"? PyCharm is an IDE, not s package.

Comment: What format is your data? Can you give a minimal example of your problem?